# Programmatically build a hyperlink to a named range in Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, named-ranges

I have a spreadsheet with lots of named ranges, and I'd like to have a sort of table of contents which provides hyperlinks to jump to them.

In the UI I can create a hyperlink to a named range, which ends up with the format:

`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxxx/edit#rangeid=yyyyy`

Where xxxx is a long spreadsheet id, and yyyy is a series of digits.

Since I have an awful lot of these, I'd like to use Google  Apps Script to generate all of these links programatically. I can find the named range objects using [Spreadsheet.getRangeByName](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getrangebynamename), but I can't find a way to get a rangeid from this.

Comment: See the [NamedRange class documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/document/named-range) where you will find getId()

Comment: Sadly, that document is for Google Docs, not Google Sheets. I've hit it a few times this afternoon!

Comment: Sorry, wrong one.  [Try this one.](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/named-range)  - with no id...

Comment: I found named ranges in [the external Google Sheets REST API](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets#NamedRange) - and tried it in the [API explorer](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) but sadly the namedRangeIds returned don't seem to work in this context.

Comment: I ran a couple scripts looking to see if something was not documented and could not find anything.  I show sections without using named ranges, but the actual range, so get the R1 notation of the range and generate the link as:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/xxxx/edit#gid=zzzz&range=A1:D6 where zzzz = the Sheet ID.  Obtain it with `var key = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName).getSheetId();`

Comment: That's a decent workaround. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137048/discussion-between-peter-russell-and-karl-s).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't appear that this is possible, but as a workaround, [Karl_S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3354226/karl-s) suggested using a range link which does work:

```
function createNamedRangeUrl(name) {
  var root = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var range = root.getRangeByName(name); 
  var sheetId = range.getSheet().getSheetId(); 
  var rangeCode = range.getA1Notation(); 
  return ("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/" + 
  root.getId() + "/edit#gid=" + sheetId + "&range=" + rangeCode); 
}
```

Comment: If you change something on a spreadsheet (add/remove rows) this link (with direct address) will  break unfortunately

Comment: Yes, it's unfortunate. In my situation it didn't matter, because I was regenerating all the links on each run.

Comment: If you need not to navigate, but to submit a value to a given cell  you can use this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77453492/3525368

Answer (score 2):

You can get id of named range using Advanced Google service: **Google Sheets API**. Turn it on at *Resources - Advanced Google services...*

Then use [`spreadsheets.get`](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/get) to get your Google Sheet data including named ranges info:

```
var spreadsheetId = '...';

var ssData = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId);
var namedRanges = ssData.namedRanges;

Logger.log(namedRanges);
```

Result:

[image]

---

Note: `namedRangeId` returned by API is obfuscated (?) and you cannot use it directly to create link programmatically. For some reason it different from what seen in UI:

[image]

Comment: I presume these are the same ids returned by the REST API. As we both noticed, these sadly don't seem to work in links.

Answer (score -3):

```
var fullSpreadsheetLink = "full spreadsheet link goes here"
var spreadsheetTabName = "tab name goes here"

var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(fullSpreadsheetLink);
var sheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName(spreadsheetTabName);

var myCell = sheet.getRange("A1");
var linkCell = sheet.getRange("A2")

var dataSourceUrl = myCell.getDataSourceUrl();
var urlArray = dataSourceUrl.split("&");

linkCell.setValue("=HYPERLINK(\"#"+urlArray[3]+"&"+urlArray[4]+"\",\"link to A1\")");
```

Comment: Code only answers with no commentary are not useful. Explain your code, your process, your solution, especially since this is a late answer.

Comment: Range.getDataSourceUrl() returns a full link with &range=<a1notation> at the end. It's not a named range id.