# Google Sheets Scripts: Can you get a range from a rangeId?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My google sheet has a cell on `sheet1` that contains a link to a cell on `sheet2`. In my function, I am able to get the link url, but cannot figure out how to get a range from the `rangeId`:

```
var link = generatorSheet.getRange(currRow, 2)
var linkUrl = link.getRichTextValue().getLinkUrl()

Logger.log(linkUrl)  // linkUrl = "rangeid=1843553975"
```

I've tried using `getRangeByName` and various other functions but keep getting a null value back, not a Range object.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: My overall goal in this is to iterate over each row in sheet1, where each cell in column 2 links to a cell in sheet2.  I need to take the value from the cell in sheet2 and copy it into sheet3.  In sheet1, there's a check box in column 1 of each row, so that's what I'm using to determine whether or not the linked to value will be copied.  I'll have a button to kick off my function and populate sheet3, and it has to assume these links are already in place - they were done by hand prior

Comment: I do not think it is supported by GAS. You may consider to use A1 notation (`range=B2:D4`) instead.

Comment: What is the contents of `generatorSheet.getRange(currRow,2)`?

Comment: This is an issue relative to the problem https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129841094

Comment: Is there a way to get A1 notation from the range id?  Or can I retrieve the link from a different function?

The contents of the cell that generatorSheet.getRange(currRow,2) is pointing to is text with a link.  When I click on the cell, it says it is linked to 'sheet2!A1', but I'm not sure how to get that in the code.  If I hard code that into this `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getRangeByName('sheet2!A1');` I get a range object for the linked to cell, which is what I want.  But it's getting the 'sheet2!A1' info within the function that I'm not sure how to do.

Comment: For more context, I'm creating a tool for a friend who already has a spreadsheet with a column of links to different sheets. I'd prefer not to have to tell her to change all her links if it can be avoided.

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to retrieve the cell reference programmatically if you only know the `rangeid`.

Comment: What is the purpose of being able to retrieve rangeid?

Comment: It's not that there is a purpose, but thats the actual link. `#rangeid=1843553975` The web browser uses JavaScript  to highlight the range. But this id isn't documented anywhere in the apps script documentation, AFAIK.

Comment: @MikeSteelson I don't think she has any namedranges. The `rangeid` is created when a user creates a link  to the range of cells.

Comment: @TheMaster : Thanks for your advices. However, I only know 2 ways to link to cell (not sheet or webpage): first by formula and I can retrieve sheet and A1 notation of range, or second way by Ctrl + K to a named range and I get the rangeid. Is there a third way i don't know and give the rangeid when searching for the range? (sorry for my english, I am French) ... edit : ok I found the way to link by user interface to a range. Thx.

Answer (score 2):

When you create an hyperlink to a range using the user interface, you are facing [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129841094). I think you may have to change the way of designing the hyperlink and try to define it by the formula

```
=hyperlink("#gid=123456789&range=A2","go to ...")
```

and then you will retrieve the range by

```
Logger.log(linkUrl.match(/(?<=range=).*/g))
```

Answer (score 1):

For documentation purposes,

This is a url hash fragment:

```
#rangeid=1843553975
```

The id seems to be created, when  inserting a link to a range using the user interface. This is **distinctly different** from a namedRange When clicked, it's appended to the url in the browser, i.e.,`https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/id/edit#rangeid=1843553975`. Once appended, through `onpopstate` javascript event, the range linked to the id is highlighted in the browser/app.

NamedRanges has a similar workflow. It also provides a `rangeid=<10 digit ID>`. But, it also has a name attached to it. But even in this case, the rangeid is not retrievable, though Sheets API provides a [obfuscated range id](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61121015).

There was a feature request made to Google, but it was made obsolete, because of lack of response on the part of the requestor:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/162810351

You may [create a new similar issue there](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=191640&template=824113) with a link to this answer. Once created, link the issue here.

Other related trackers:

- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129841094
- https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/134986436