# Google spreadsheet get parameters from URL

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, oauth, google-sheets

I have an app, that links one service with Google Sheets by OAuth 1.0.

I click "login" in addon menu, send signature and callback domain (current sheet). Then in service I click on button, get request token and it returns me to the specified domain with parameters.

```
function onOpen(e)
{
    Logger.log( SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getUrl() );
    Logger.log( e.source.getUrl() );
}
```

But `.getUrl()` doesn't contain them.

According to [>**this**<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687592/google-spreadsheet-reading-parameters-from-its-own-url) I can't use `doGet(e)` in Sheets and, because of OAuth, I can't use Web App, because I still need to pass these parameters to Sheets.

I tried to get it on client-side by `window.top.location.href`, but had cross-domain errors.

**Question:** Can I get it? Or is it impossible?

Comment: See then [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25690127/1595451) by Sergei Insas on the referred question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google spreadsheet reading parameters from its own URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25687592/google-spreadsheet-reading-parameters-from-its-own-url)

Comment: @Rubén, I've already referred to this question above. This doesn't solve the problem through Web App, because (if I have Web App) service, that provide OAuth, opens it and Web App doesn't know about Sheets and can't write there

Comment: The answer is that it's not possible by using a bounded script, as was explained on the referred answer. By the other hand it's not clear for me what do you mean by "Web App doesn't know about Sheets". A GAS Web App could write/read values to spreadsheets using the Spreadsheet Service (SpreadsheetApp).

Comment: @Rubén, I think I understood what you mean. I'll go try. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, a partial answer to my question:

We need 2 different scripts. The first as Sheets web addon, the second as Web App. Next, we need to implement all the steps presented in the screenshot:
[image: steps]
1) After steps 0, 1, 2 Service Provider should redirect us to Helper script (`Web App`) with the following code:

```
function doGet(e)
{
    var token    = e.parameter.oauth_token,
        code     = e.parameter.oauth_verifier,
        response;

        if(token && code && Root.setVerificationCode(token, code))
            response = "Success";
        else
            response = 'Error';

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(response);
}
```

Here we retrieving GET parameters and send them to Sheets web addon (`Root`).
Click `Resources -> Libraries` and add your addon as library. `Root` is just an identifier.

2) Sheets addon code:

```
function setVerificationCode(token, code)
{
    var oauth = new OAuth();
    if(oauth.getAccessToken(code))
    {
        // change menu here
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```

These are full steps you need to implement OAuth 1.0.

P.S. Now I have problems with changing menu, but it'll be my next question.